How Can I Simplify a Radial Graph Network While Preserving Key Information?
I have created a radial graph network to visualize connections between brain regions. Each region is represented by a circle, with unique colors used for the regions. The circle border indicates group/subnetwork membership, and the size reflects a network metric (betweenness centrality). However, the use of many colors seems to increase cognitive load for the reader. Could you suggest ways to simplify the visualization while retaining these three key aspects:
1.  Identifying which node represents which brain region and their connections
2.  Indicating subnetwork membership
3.  Showing the size of the node to represent the network metric scale


Here is a variation where I used shape and intensity to represent features, as suggested in the comments. Please let me know what you think:


You could use shape instead of colour for one of the dimensions of information - perhaps to replace the outer circle.

But with different shapes, it's difficult to compare sizes among different shapes. In that case, I would lose the feature the network metric.

@LCheng You can use colour intensity instead of size for continuous variables. Though that is easier if you're not also manipulating colour itself.

Thanks, I made modifications based on your suggestions. Let me know it's visually more straight forward.
